# Generate a stream with delays for each emit in dart

Tags: dart, reactive, rxdart

I want to emit values in a stream from a list with a specific delay in dart.

So, from [1,2,3], which is a regular List I want to emit values like `1...2...3` in separated events.

I tried something like this

```
List<int> myList = [1,2,3];
Subject _current = BehaviorSubject<int>();
Stream<int> get current$ => _current.stream.delay(Duration(seconds:1));

myList.forEach(current.add);
```

But I get `...123` instead, so this is delaying the whole stream 1 seconds, rather than every value in the list.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to avoid rxdart, you can use simple transformation function like:

```
Stream<T> streamDelayer<T>(Stream<T> inputStream, Duration delay) async* {
  await for (final val in inputStream) {
    yield val;
    await Future.delayed(delay);
  }
}

void main() {
  var s = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]);
  streamDelayer(s, Duration(seconds: 1)).forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: moving yield below the await will delay the first value also.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart) 0.25.0:

```dart
final Stream<int> stream = 
    Rx.range(1, 3)
      .asyncExpand((event) => 
        event == 1
        ? Stream.value(event) // return first value immediately
        : Rx.timer(event, Duration(seconds: 1))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

using `interval` from `rxdart` package

```dart
Stream.fromIterable(List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i))
        .interval(Duration(milliseconds: 10))
        .listen((v) {
      print(v);
});
```

Comment: It's emitting values like: `...1...2...3`
But it should emit like: `1...2...3`

Comment: @DavidAraujo if you mean it starts from 0 and should start from 1, change `=> i` to `=> i+1`

Comment: @Ali80 I think the original commenter meant that they don't want an initial delay before the first emitted event.

Answer (score 0):

The [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart)

package provides a [delay](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/delay.html) transformer or method that does that

> ```
> new Observable.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4])
>   .delay(new Duration(seconds: 1))
>   .listen(print); // [after one second delay] prints 1, 2, 3, 4 immediately
> ```

There are others like [debounce](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/debounce.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that's doing the same that I have, it waits for 1 second and then prints immediately; what I want is to print 1, wait 1 second, print 2, wait 1 second, print 3, wait 1 second, print 4, wait 1 second.

Comment: I actually got the answer from rxdart itself, using concatMap, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working

```
Observable.range(myList)
  .concatMap((i) =>
    new Observable.timer(i, new Duration(seconds: 1))
  .listen(print);
```

From the [rxdart](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/concatMap.html) documentation itself. Thanks Günter for the good tip.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution using StreamController, which gives you the ability to control the stream using pause and resume as follows:

```
List<int> myList = [1, 2, 3];
StreamController current = StreamController();
late StreamSubscription listenController;

void waitFunction() async {
  listenController.pause();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  listenController.resume();
}

myList.forEach(current.add);

listenController = current.stream.listen((event) async {
  print(event);
  waitFunction();
});
```